# "If" statement with "and" operator - daytimes

Tags: bash, if-statement

I have issues with the last if in this example:

```
#!/bin/bash

sunrise="05:00:00";
currenttime=$(date -u +%H:%M:%S);
sunset="18:00:00"


if [[ "$sunrise" < "$currenttime" ]] ; then
    echo works1;
fi

if [[ "$sunset" > "$currenttime" ]] ; then
    echo works2;
fi

# during the day:
if [[ "$sunrise" < "$currenttime" ]] && [[ "$currenttime" > "$sunset" ]] ; then
    echo works3;
fi
```

I get the output of the first two `echo` but not from the last one.

What am I doing wrong?

Of course I'm doing this tests now at 11:30.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If current time is `11:30`, then `11:30` is smaller than `18:00` so the last condition of script is false.

Just to make this answer a bit more useful, you can use `set -x` to print all the steps that the script does which helps to find this kind of bugs.

And also, use "seconds from epoch" when working with time and transform them back at the end of the script: working with integer is much easier and safer than working with strings.

Comment: I'm dumb... .-.

Thanks.

Comment: It's not that easy for me. What you see here is just an example, but the real code fetch sunrise and sunset times from the web. I didn't write that part of the code, and so I have to learn how to change so to get seconds.

Comment: just look at `date --help` if I remember correctly something like `date -s "18:00" +%s` should do the job (probably you will have to check the syntax a bit...

Comment: Done! :D
Thanks. I had to change a few things since from the web I can get sunrise and sunset times in seconds only from the last midnight. I did it. Thank you. :)

Answer (score 1):

I suspect you want this:

```sh
if [[ "$currenttime" <= "$sunrise" ]] ; then
    echo "before sunrise"
fi
if [[ "$currenttime" >= "$sunset" ]] ; then
    echo "after sunset"
fi
if [[ "$sunrise" < "$currenttime" && "$currenttime" < "$sunset" ]] ; then
    echo "daytime"
fi
```